# Why is the Links Manager visible?

Tags: theme-development, customization, wp-admin, links, admin-menu

The admin panel of my WordPress (4.7.2) installation on my hosting (godaddy) has "Links" section enabled.

I set it up a few seconds ago with storefront theme. Then removed storefront and activated starter theme _S (underscores).

Even though I **did not** use following code, the links section is visible. Why is that?

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_link_manager_enabled', '__return_true' );
```

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have any links in that section?  The codex also states that if you have any links, it will be visible.

Comment: @rudtek I tryied this and created a link but it did not work. Theme wanted me to install links manager plugin if I want to open this section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install WordPress using the GoDaddy cPanel then GoDaddy will automatically install a number of [Must Use Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) in your installation. These plugins are invisible and you can't disable them by normal means. One of these plugins is enabling the Link Manager.

Aside: If you haven't worked on your site yet I recommend [installing WordPress manually](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress). The plugins GoDaddy adds will add unnecessary features and sometimes conflict with other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a brand-new site, or one that you've recently upgraded to 4.7.2? If the latter, here's one possibility:

> If you are upgrading from a previous version of WordPress with any active links, the Links Manager will continue to function as normal.

From [Codex » Links Manager](https://codex.wordpress.org/Links_Manager).

Also, try disabling all your plugins and switch to a WordPress default theme (like Twenty Fourteen, Twenty Fifteen, Twenty Sixteen, etc.) to see if the behaviour persists.

Comment: Installation is brand new, I did not upgrade it but installed using the godaddy cpanel application installation. I have also read the same thing on codex, but wanted to debug and see what is the reason behind it.

Comment: You could also try adding `add_filter( 'pre_option_link_manager_enabled', '__return_false', 9999 );` to your theme's `functions.php` file to see if that turns off the Link Manager.

Answer (score -1):

Remove this line from `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_link_manager_enabled', '__return_true' );
```

Or use remove filter hook

Comment: Hi, I don't have this code in my functions.php.

Comment: so reinstall it manually

Comment: could you tell me which version are you using?

Comment: "which function" is what I am looking for here :), I don't know what is the reason.

Comment: could you tell me which version are you using?

Comment: it is ----> 4.7.2

Comment: list options were available before 3.5 version. after 3.5 version if some want to use this option they should use filter hook. I am not sure about the current version. Maybe again WordPress add this option. Another solution If you don't what to show this option you may use CSS to hide it. li#menu-links {
    display: none;
}